# How to add a new column in data frame by dividing values in an existing column, specifically, in the same existing column?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I want to use the `mutate` function to create a new column.

I can't figure out how to do it because the values in the new column are to be quotients of values from another column in my data frame.

Usually when I've used `mutate` before the values were in different columns like `mutate(newcolumn = colX_values / colY_values)` but this time, both parts of the equation are in the same column. The main difference is that I want the female values to be divided by the male values.

````
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
```

```{r}
race = c("all", "all", "black", "black")
earnings = c(74467, 57202, 44725, 40974)
gender = c("male", "female", "male", "female")
work_status = c("FT", "FT", "FT", "FT")

data.frame(race, earnings, gender, work_status)
```

```{r}
earnings %>%
  filter(work_status == "FT")
```
````

I eventually want a 5th column that consists of the the female earnings / male earnings per each race. so for all the male rows there should be the number 1 in the new column and in all the female rows it should be the result of 57202/74467.

I am just not sure how to get that result.

Comment: Sorry please disregard the filtering.

Comment: hmmm, so I created a new column using `mutate(new_earnings = c("74467", "74467", "44725", "44725")). and now I plan to just divide that way. I am still curious if there is a more direct way to go about solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df %>% 
  spread(gender,earnings) %>% 
  mutate(Ratio=female/male)
```

Output:

```
 race work_status female  male     Ratio
1   all          FT  57202 74467 0.7681523
2 black          FT  40974 44725 0.9161319
```